# How to fix these weird shading problems?

Tags: shaders

when ever i use the Boolean modifier i usually see these weird cuts in the shading, the same thing happened when extruding too. Does anyone know how to fix this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might have some artifacts in your mesh after using the modifier. If it's just a shading issue, you could try turn on "Auto Smooth" in the object data properties and see if that fixes it. Auto Smooth also works best when your shading is set to Smooth. Another thing that can help is to clear the custom normal data on the model to make sure there aren't any other settings affecting  your shading.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices), it tends to create artifacts for example when the faces are non planar. You can try to fix it with the *Auto Smooth* option:

[image]

[image]

But the best is to fix your topology with quads:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i went ahead and remade the piece, trying to keep the quads consistent, it looks pretty good so far, and thanks for the tip.